# extend arrow to match width of the above line

Tags: arrows

How can you extend arrow to match the width of text in the above line?

I want to get a result like this.

```
X -> Y -> Z
 ------->
```

And the best way I could think of was:

```
X
\begin{array}{c}
    \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} Y \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} \\
    \xrightarrow{\hfill h \hfill}
\end{array}
Z
```

But the arrow is short. I want to extend the width of the

```
\xrightarrow{\hfill h \hfill}
```

to match the width of

```
\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} Y \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a small complete document that shows your setting and what you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  X
\begin{array}{c}
    \eqmathbox{\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} Y \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}} \\[-1ex]
    \xrightarrow[\hskip-0.7ex\eqmathbox{\scriptstyle h}\hskip-0.8ex]{}
\end{array}
Z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The result is exactly what I wanted. Box and glue are things I haven't yet understood. Trying to figure out how your document is working.

Comment: Actually, it was fothund by trial and error: `\xrightarrow` measures what is above or below it, and adds small lengths on both sides. I don't know how these lengths are chosen, but I removed small lengths at both ends of the  `\eqmathbox` with `\hskip -…` until it seemed correct. I measured these lengths in ex units, so that if you use another font size, it should (hopefully) still work

Comment: Is \hskip needed? I was testing the script to understand the behavior and it seems to me that I am getting the same result by changing \xrightarrow[\hskip-0.7ex\eqmathbox{\scriptstyle h}\hskip-0.8ex]{} to \xrightarrow[\eqmathbox{\scriptstyle h}]{} Is there some reason to add /hskip?

Comment: I added it because the arrow ends were not exactly aligned with the other arrows above – the \xrightarrow itself is lightly larger than what's above or below it, and I don't know exactly by how much.

Comment: I see. Thank you.